# There is some sytax issue with CREATE_TASKS_TABLE String

Tags: android, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

this code is from my DatabaseHelper Class
//These are two tables

```
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";
private static final String TABLE_TASK_LIST = "task_list";
```

// These are Table Columns names

```
private static final String KEY_PK = "_id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_DETAILS = "details";
private static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
private static final String KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID = "fk_tasklist_id";
```

//these are the strings which will be assigned to db.exeSQL

```
private static final String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
+ TABLE_TASKS 
+ "(" 
+ KEY_PK
+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
+ KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT," + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT," 
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+ KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID + ")" 
+ "REFERENCES " 
+ TABLE_TASK_LIST + "("+ KEY_PK + ")" 
+ ")";
private static final String CREATE_TASK_LIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
+ TABLE_TASK_LIST + "(" + KEY_PK
+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT" +    ")";
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
try {
db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);// create task table
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("onCreate Error", "TASKS_TABLE not created");
}
try {
db.execSQL(CREATE_TASK_LIST_TABLE);// create task list table
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("onCreate Error", "TASK_LIST_TABLE not created");
}
}
```

String is causing problem when i try to insert data it says table tasks has no column named  fk_tasklist_id

Comment: so why don't you fix up this code to use the proper field name that IS in that table? We can't help you, since you haven't told us ANYTHING about the actual table structure.

Comment: i thought i had provided all the relevant information, CL has already shown me the problem. anyway thanks Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    details TEXT,
    notes TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_tasklist_id) REFERENCES task_list(_id)
)
```

In this table definition, there is indeed no column named `fk_tasklist_id`.

To define such a column, add it to the column list:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    details TEXT,
    notes TEXT,
    fk_tasklist_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_tasklist_id) REFERENCES task_list(_id)
)
```

Alternatively, put the FK constraint on this column:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    details TEXT,
    notes TEXT,
    fk_tasklist_id INTEGER REFERENCES task_list(_id)
)
```

Comment: your answer helped thanks it was missing the column